# A VBA code to transfer data from a sheet to another one

Tags: excel, vba

Here’s my problem, I’ve a table in sheet named « Formulaire du journal », in this sheet the user enter the informations and fill the table (screenshot 1), the informations of this table is trensfered to another sheet called « Journal » (screenshot 2)

The table should be transferred (screenshot 6)

I followed a video on youtube so I tried a VBA code but i’ve a problem (screenshot 3 and 4)
Here’s the code I used :

```
Option Explicit

Sub addinfo(pages, lignes)

    Dim dl As Long
    Dim page As String
    page = pages
    'trouver la dernière ligne du tableau
    If Sheets(page).Range("E3") = Empty Then
        dl = 3
    Else
        Sheets(page).ListObjects(1).ListRows.Add
        dl = Sheets(page).Range("E2").End(xlDown).Row + 
    End If
    'placer dans le journal spécifique
    With Sheets(page)
        .Range("E" & dl) = .Range("D7") 'La date
        .Range("F" & dl) = Range("D13" & lignes) 'N° de compte débit
        .Range("G" & dl) = Range("F13" & lignes) 'N° de compte crédit
        .Range("J" & dl) = Range("G13" & lignes) 'Montant débit
        .Range("K" & dl) = Range("H13" & lignes) 'Montant crédit
        .Range("L" & dl) = Range("D9") 'libellé d'opération
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have a `ListObject` (**Table**) on the worksheet being referenced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things I don't understand (e.g. why is `pages` assigned to `page`, what is the value of `pages`, what is the value of `lignes`, why does the code read from cells `D13` and `F13` when the image and comments suggest it should read from `D13` and `E13`).

Although you've provided a lot of detail/information in your question (which is good), it's difficult to know what exactly is causing the issue.

- The fifth screenshot suggests perhaps there is no `ListObject` on `Sheets(page)`, hence run-time error '9'.
- The second screenshot suggests this too (cell `F4` appears to be selected, is in inside your "table" body, but there is no `Outils de tableau > Creation` AKA `Table Tools` shown in the ribbon at the top of screen. This might suggest the "table" on `Journal` sheet is just a regular range formatted to look like a table -- but not actually an Excel table/`ListObject`).

I've basically re-written what I think your code is trying to do.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub TransferToJournalSheet()
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formulaire du journal")

    Dim sourceTable As ListObject
    Debug.Assert sourceSheet.ListObjects.Count > 0 ' If code pauses on this line, check if you have a table on sourceSheet
    Set sourceTable = sourceSheet.ListObjects(1) ' If there is a name, you can specify the name instead of index.

    Dim destinationSheet As Worksheet
    Set destinationSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Journal")

    Dim destinationRowIndex As Long
    destinationRowIndex = destinationSheet.Cells(destinationSheet.Rows.CountLarge, "E").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Debug.Assert destinationRowIndex > 2

    Debug.Assert sourceTable.Range.Rows.Count > 1 ' If code pauses on this line, check if there is any data to transfer.
    With sourceTable.DataBodyRange
        destinationSheet.Cells(destinationRowIndex, "E").Resize(.Rows.Count).FormulaLocal = sourceSheet.Range("D7").Value
        destinationSheet.Range("F" & destinationRowIndex, "G" & destinationRowIndex).Resize(.Rows.Count).Value2 = .Columns("B:C").Value
        destinationSheet.Range("J" & destinationRowIndex, "K" & destinationRowIndex).Resize(.Rows.Count).Value2 = .Columns("E:F").Value
        destinationSheet.Cells(destinationRowIndex, "L").Resize(.Rows.Count).FormulaLocal = sourceSheet.Range("D9").Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

concerning the code I just followed a video on Youtube and tried to adapt it to my project, I tried the code you provided but it doesn't work too.